# Probability theory: two consecutive heads in first time

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, random-variables

What is the expectation of two consecutive heads in first time? I tried something like this: let's say that $\xi$ is a random variable that says the first time when we have two consecutive heads. For example, $\xi$ = 2 if we have two consecutive heads in two first attempts, $\xi$ = 3 if we have two consecutive heads from the second and third atempts etc. if $p$ - probability of head ($\frac{1}{2}$), $q$ - probability of tail ($\frac{1}{2}$), $P(\xi = 2) = (\frac{1}{2})^2$, $P(\xi = 3) = (\frac{1}{2})^3$, $P(\xi = 4) = 2*(\frac{1}{2})^4 (TTHH, HTHH)$, $P(\xi = 5) = 3*(\frac{1}{2})^5 (TTTHH, HTTHH, THTHH)$ etc. Then we have $E(\xi) = 2*(\frac{1}{2})^2 + \sum_{k=3}^\infty k * (k-2)*(\frac{1}{2})^k$. But the sum of this condition is 3 although it should be 6. What is wrong?

Comment: You seem to be extrapolating from a very small sample.  Already, with $\zeta=6$, there are $TTTTHH, HTTTHH, THTTHH, TTHTHH, HTHTHH$, so $5$ cases...where your linear extrapolation would yield $4$.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3954418/expected-number-of-coin-tosses-until-hh-in-a-row) is a duplicate for your underlying question.

Comment: And [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2515784/proving-the-number-of-n-length-binary-strings-with-no-consecutive-1s-b-n) is a way to count the binary strings with no $11$, which is basically what you need to do the problem your way.  (Technically, you need to count those strings that do not end in $1$, but it should be easy for you to prove that this is the same as the general number shifted in length by one).

Comment: @lulu Thank you