# Stochastic processes for beginers (good links and books)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I've a syllabus like that..

Markov chains with finite and countable state space. Classification of states.
Limiting behavior of n state transition probabilities. Stationary distribution. Branching process.
Random walk. Gambler’s ruin problem. Markov processes in continuous time. Poisson’s process
Partial correlation. Multiple correlation. Advanced theory of linear estimation

Comment: See this [thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15431/good-introductory-book-for-markov-processes) and that [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20898/recommendation-on-stochastic-process-books?rq=1).

Answer (score 3):

Standard texts on Markov chains are :

- Norris: Markov Chains
- D. Stroock: An Introduction to Markov Processes

Markov processes in cont. time is a more advanced subject. Literature suggestions: 
Last chapter in Cinlar: Probability and Stochastics; Getoor/ Blumenthal: Markov Processes and Potential theory.